# how to check if sentences in csv file exist in a column in another csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a method to check if sentences in dictionary.csv exists in file.csv's column. But the code is doing exact matching instead of checking word by word of each row. Below are the codes i have so far

```
import csv
import pandas as pd


news=pd.read_csv("file.csv")
dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary.csv", squeeze=True)


pattern = '|'.join(dictionary)


news["contain diseases1"] = np.where(news["STORY"].str.contains(pattern, na=False),1, 0
)

news.to_csv("clues.csv", index=False)
```

These are what in dictionary.csv and file.csv

```
dictionary.csv

sigmoid colon cancer
pecific early onset breast cancer syndrome
```

```
file.csv
id STORY
0  Ari has a colon cancer
1  Cancer is an epidemic
2  Breast cancer has been affecting many female
```

```
clues.csv
id STORY                                         contain diseases1 
0  Ari has a colon cancer                            0
1  Cancer is an epidemic                             0
2  Breast cancer has been affecting many female      0
```

I should get 1 for all of the rows in the clues.csv, because for e.g,there is colon cancer in row 0 file.csv but i kept on getting 0 instead

Comment: your problem is still not clear to me what exactly you want to perform. Please state exactly.

Comment: @vBrail i wanted to check if sentences in dictionary.csv, exist in file.csv, i was able to do a method to do this, but, the method does exact matching instead of matching word by word from the dictionary.csv

Comment: You want to check if a word in dictionary.csv sentence exists in a sentence of file.csv? If so, do you want to check this sentence by sentence, i.e, are the lengths of dictionary.csv and file.csv equal ?

Comment: @Devrim no they are not equal

Comment: So do you want to perform a full scan ? For every sentence in file.csv do you want to check for all words in entire dictionary.csv ?

Comment: @Devrim something like that, for further understanding you may look at what's in the dictionary.csv and file.csv.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit ambigious, but I assume you try to search for words in sentences of `file.csv` within entire `dictionary.csv` file. You can do it that way:

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

news=pd.read_csv("file.csv")
dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary.csv", squeeze=True, header=None)

dictionary = dictionary.apply(lambda x: x.split())

def compress_dictionary(df):
    words = []
    for seq in dictionary.ravel():
        words += seq
    return words

words = compress_dictionary(dictionary)

news['clues'] = news.sentences.apply(lambda x: 1 \
     if set(x.split()) and set(words) else 0)
```

**Output**

For convenience I created a new column in `news` data frame as clues, and fill it if any word in that sentence exists among the words of `dictionary.csv`.

```
   id                                     sentences  clues
0   0                        Ari has a colon cancer      1
1   1                         Cancer is an epidemic      1
2   2  Breast cancer has been affecting many female      1
```

Comment: this code gave outputs 1 to all of my sentences, may i know why?

Comment: since it looks for all words in dictionary.csv for each sentence in "file.csv"